# Variation dropdowns into radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert dropdown to radio buttons on the fly using jquery, here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select#pa_size option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected', true).parent().trigger('change');
});
```

this code get me the radio button. But it cant work for [add-to-cart](http://jokhontokhon.elevenbd.com/product/lawrance-polo-tee-jack-jones/) option.
Please click add-to-cart link for see the direct page.

Comment: Can you share the code so we can mess around with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //Get Exising Select Options    
$('select#pa_size').each(function(i, select){
    var $select = $(select);
    $select.find('option').each(function(j, option){
        var $option = $(option);
        // Create a radio:
        var $radio = $('<input type="radio" />');
        // Set name and value:
        $radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val());
        // Set checked if the option was selected
        if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
        // Insert radio before select box:
        $select.before($radio);
        // Insert a label:
        $select.before(
          $("<label />").attr('for', $select.attr('name')).text($option.text())
        );
        // Insert a <br />:
        $select.before("<br/>");
    });
    $select.remove();
});

$('.single_variation_wrap').css('display','block');
```

});
// This is the latest code. same problem